# Java SDK to get specific folder size in aws s3 bucket

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I'm finding difficulty in retrieving folder size from my s3 bucket. 
For Ex: Suppose structuring is like

```
/home/ - 100GB
/home/10sOffiles/ - 10GB
/home/100sOffiles/ - 90GB
/home/100sOffiles/subfolderswith1000images - 60GB
```

I wanna find out the "subfolderswith1000images" this folder size. Using java sdk of aws

Comment: Have you explored any of the options described in this ServerFault post:  https://serverfault.com/questions/84815/how-can-i-get-the-size-of-an-amazon-s3-bucket?

Comment: Don't know why Stephen C marked this question as duplicate. I'm not able find any solution related to it in java anywhere on stack overflow. I think you need to look at the above links first